# Strange piece of Delphi Code

Tags: java, delphi

I am currently in the process of translating Delphi code into Java code, and I need some help understanding what a certain line of code does. I have looked around online and cannot find what this specific part of the code does.

I understand what Writeln(...) from below does. 
I also understand that 'f' is the destination of the writeln(...) from the code below. 
I also understand what the FloatToStrF(...) function and its parameters are, but I am confused about the small piece attached to the end of the FloatToStrF(...):12 as seen below.

`Writeln (f,FloattoStrF (llat,ffFixed,8,2):12,FloatToStrF(llon,ffFixed,8,2):12,InttoStr(elev):12,'    ',zz);`

What does the ':12' mean when attached to the end of FloatToStrF(...) or to InttoStr(...)? Does that mean what type it is?
Is its type being changed to '12'?
I know ' : ' is used for specifying types of variables in delphi, but what is it doing in this instance behind a FloatToStr(...)?

If a little more context is needed then here is a bit more of the code:

```
AssignFile(F, AppPath+'\Markov98.ctl');
Rewrite(F);
Writeln (f,FloattoStrF (llat,ffFixed,8,2):12,FloatToStrF(llon,ffFixed,8,2):12,InttoStr(elev):12,'    ',zz);
CloseFile(F);
```

Comment: It's documented: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Write

Comment: Should be "Strange piece of **Pascal** Code. This goes all the way back to Wirth

Comment: Here, the `:12` turns the output of StrFloat into a string with at least 12 elements, if necessary padded with spaces. This is plain Pascal.

Comment: Thank you guys very much. I realize now that I was looking for the wrong thing all along.

Comment: Please try it online in [http://ideone.com/QDBkOu](http://ideone.com/QDBkOu) and see the difference. There is no magic and nothing strange here...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a width specifier. It is standard pascal and available in every pascal dialect.

For each value that you want to write out you can specify a width and (for float values) a precision:

```
writeln(f, 'Hi':5, 3.14159:7:2);
```

See the Delphi documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Write (or the FreePascal documentation http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Formatting_output)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know, but the functionality is from standard pascal, so it doesn't matter whether the description is from Delphi, FreePascal or any other dialect

Comment: Thank you very much. I was looking for the wrong thing all along. I have never even lookd at pascal, but thank you guys for the help.

Answer (score 5):

The Writeln procedure is a compiler *magic* function and is just an extension of the Write procedure, After executing *Write*, *Writeln* writes an end-of-line marker.

Now what you looking for is explained in the [documentation of the System.Write procedure](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Write)

> A Write(Ln) parameter has the form:
>
> > OutExpr [: MinWidth [: DecPlaces ] ]
>
> MinWidth specifies the minimum field width, which must be greater than
>   0. Exactly MinWidth characters are written (using leading blanks if necessary) except when OutExpr has a value that must be represented in
>   more than MinWidth characters. In that case, enough characters are
>   written to represent the value of OutExpr. Likewise, if MinWidth is
>   omitted, then the necessary number of characters is written to
>   represent the value of OutExpr.
>
> DecPlaces specifies the number of decimal places in a fixed-point
>   representation of one of the Real types. It can be specified only if
>   OutExpr is one of the Real types, and if MinWidth is also specified.
>   When MinWidth is specified, it must be greater than or equal to 0.